# Remove value of array by key array in actionscript

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I have two array:

```
var valueArr:Array = [50,46,64,85,98,63,46,38,51,24,37,58,48,14,28];
var keyArr:Array = [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14];
```

- keyArr: container key of valueArr

I want to remove values of valueArr array by key of keyArr array:

```
var resultArr:Array = [50,46,64,85,98];
```

Comment: have you tried with splice? you are looping downwards through the keyArr and splice valuArr like so `valueArr.splice(keyArr[i], 1);` where i is index of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var valueArr:Array = [50,46,64,85,98,63,46,38,51,24,37,58,48,14,28];
var keyArr:Array = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];
trace("valueArr",valueArr);//valueArr 50,46,64,85,98,63,46,38,51,24,37,58,48,14,28
trace("keyArr", keyArr);//keyArr 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14
var i:int;
for (i = keyArr.length; --i >= 0; )
{
    if (keyArr[i] < valueArr.length)
    {
        trace(valueArr.splice(keyArr[i], 1));
/*returned by above line
28
14
48
58
37
24
51
38
46
63
*/
    }
}
trace("valueArr",valueArr);//valueArr 50,46,64,85,98
trace("keyArr",keyArr);//keyArr 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14
```

regards